# How is 'moveSpeed' used here without being defined anywhere?

Tags: python, pygame

I found this pygame project online and was curious how 'moveSpeed' is being used as a number? like below?

```
def move(self, moveSpeed):
        self.x -= moveSpeed
```

```
class HurdleManager:
    def __init__(self, scale, spawnRange):
        self.img = transform.scale(image.load('homework.png'), (7 * scale, 15 * scale))

        self.spawnRange = spawnRange
        self.hurdleList = []
        self.scale = scale


    def update(self, doSpawn, moveSpeed):
        if doSpawn:
            self.spawn()
        self.manage(moveSpeed)


    def manage(self, moveSpeed):
        hurdles2 = []

        for hurdle in self.hurdleList:
            hurdle.update(moveSpeed)

            if hurdle.onScreen():
                hurdles2.append(hurdle)


        self.hurdleList = hurdles2

    spawnTick = 0

    def spawn(self):
        if self.spawnTick >= self.spawnRange[1]:
            newHurdle = HurdleClass(windowX, self.img, 7 * self.scale, 15 * self.scale)  
            self.hurdleList.append(newHurdle)
            self.spawnTick = 0

        elif self.spawnTick > self.spawnRange[0]:
            if random.randint(0, self.spawnRange[1] - self.spawnRange[0]) == 0:
                newHurdle = HurdleClass(windowX, self.img, 7 * self.scale, 15 * self.scale)
                self.hurdleList.append(newHurdle)
                self.spawnTick = 0


        self.spawnTick += 1



hurdleManager = HurdleManager(3, (45, 90)) 


class HurdleClass:
    def __init__(self, x, img, width, height): 
        self.x = x
        self.img = img
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.y = ground - height   

    def update(self, moveSpeed):
        self.move(moveSpeed)
        self.show()

    def move(self, moveSpeed):
        self.x -= moveSpeed

    def show(self):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))

    def onScreen(self):
        if self.x + self.width > 0:
            return True
        else:                
            return False
```

Comment: For future reference, it's `\`\`\`` and not `'''` hehe, use the editors code function if you're unsure :)

Comment: ahh thanks for the correction! the person who made that game didn't put any explanation to it.. so..

Comment: `update()` is probably *(since we don't have the entire code, it's hard to tell)* called with the delta between render cycles. The time spent between two render calls will determinate how much movement should occur. Lets say you want to move 10 pixels per seconds, but only 0.5 seconds pass between each render cycles, you there for want to multiply `10 * 0.5` to get how many pixels you should move in order to honor those 10px per seconds. This is usually why time delta is passed to update functions. But again, we don't have the full code so maybe they do some other magic :)

Comment: is this the full snippet? https://pastebin.com/NwhQtsVJ

Comment: wow thank you for your answer Torxed I really appreciate it!! I don't think you would be interested in the entire code but here it is: https://pastebin.com/NwhQtsVJ

Comment: Yes Tibebes that's the code i was trying to figure out! im stuck with "class HurdleManager" and "class HurdleClass"...

Comment: well, the `moveSpeed` came all the way from `line 246` - `hurdleManager.update(True, score['gameScore'] / 50 + 3)`  (notice the second argument)

Comment: the expression is evaluated and is passed as `moveSpeed` to `hurdleManager.update( .. )`

Comment: why is the number written as 50+3? also hurdleManager.update leads to self.spawn(), could you explain how it works from there? + what happens when self.hurdleList.append(newHurdle) at line 156? does it make the spawnRange [hurdle, newHurdle, 45,46,47...89]? I'm sorry I'm asking tons of questions... you don't have to answer all my questions..!

Answer (score 1):

```
def move(self, moveSpeed):
```

`def move` says "I'm creating a function definition here. When I've finished defining it, I'd like the function to be bound to the name "move" in the current scope. Also, the function can use bindings from the current scope."

`(self, moveSpeed)` says "To run this function, I need two arguments. The first one is called self and the second one is called moveSpeed."

An argument is also known as a parameter. Just like when being asked to cut a cake, you might ask "Which cake?" and "Which knife?". In most programming languages, you pass parameters (also known as arguments) in the order each is declared. For example, given:

```
def cut(cake, knife):
    ...
```

writing `cut(a, b)` would "call" `cut` with the caller's "a" bound to the called function's "cake" variable and with the caller's "b" bound to the called function's "knife" variable.

---

In Python, you can also give the names of arguments explicitly. For example, `cut(cake=a, knife=b)` would do the same thing. These are called "keyword arguments." You don't  need to pass things in declaration order when you use keyword arguments. For example, `cut(knife=b, cake=a)` would do the same thing as well.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I did understand that self and moveSpeed are both parameters. but doesn't self.x -= moveSpeed mean self.x - moveSpeed = self.x ? I didn't get this part since moveSpeed isn't defined as number or anything (eg self.moveSped = 0 something like that)

Comment: self.x -= moveSpeed means self.x = self.x - moveSpeed

Comment: ahh my mistake yes self.x is redefined as self.x - moveSpeed but how is this possible?

Comment: the original code is from: pastebin.com/NwhQtsVJ   idk if you are interested but if you are could you explain line 246? i don't understand why this person wrote 50 + 3

Comment: @Lucio He wrote divide by 50, and add 3. I'd have to read for context and perhaps ask the author to understand the purpose.